# iOS -- require OpenGL ES 2.0 for upgrade?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

The first version of my app runs on all iOS devices. I'm considering releasing an upgrade which will only work on devices which support OpenGL ES 2.0. Is that as simple as changing the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in info.plist? If I do this, what will users on the old devices see when they try to upgrade? Or will they even be notified that there's an upgrade available?

And lastly, just want to double-check that this will work, that it's possible to change the device requirements for different versions of my app.

Answer (score 0):

I would not restrict app via UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities unless you do not want app installed. I would not restrict and check at runtime and then use new features conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to tighten hardware requirements on a published app, you may need to resubmit it under a different name.  I believe Apple does this to protect the investment of users who bought your app.

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed the case. However, I think I'm going to be able to achieve the same effect by offering upgrades/additional levels via in-app purchase. Plan is to hide the new levels which won't run well on older devices.